# Edit a specific line in a text file in python

Tags: python

I want to edit a line in a text file in python.

I have a text file

```
name:
address:
age:
```

I need to add things to some specific fileds of the above file. Basically fill some of the fields.

ex: 
The output should be

```
name:
address:xxx
age:20
```

Comment: You can't edit a file in-place. You must read it all, then replace your data, then write it back.

Comment: read all lines, modify what you need, write all lines to file.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use "xreadlines()" to manipulate the text file (eg. 1GB file).
For example, if I want to shift all the dates in the beginning of line, the following example is shown with Python code.

## inputfile: inputfile.txt

> $Name1
> Name1 xx xx
> Date    WATER  Category
> 19620701  100  a1
> 19630801 200  b1
> 19630901  150  c1
> $Name2
> Name2 xx xx
> Date    WATER  Category
> 19620701  200  a2
> 19630801  100  b2
> 19630901  300  c2
> ...

outFile:Outfile.txt. Even with the high-volume txt file, the program only takes 20s to finish the run.

> Name1
> Name1 xx xx Date
> WATER  Category
> 19620601  100  a1
> 19630701  200  b1
> 19630801  150  c1
> Name2
> Name2 xx xx
> Date    WATER  Category
> 19620601  200  a2
> 19630701  100  b2
> 19630801  300  c2
> ...

Python code:

```
inputFile=open('inputfile.txt','w')
OutFile=open('Outfile.txt'+,'w')
date0=date_init='19620601'
lines1=open(inputFile,'r').xreadlines()
for line in lines1:
    line_date=line[0:8] #Take the 1st 8 char,'19620701'
    if line_date.isdigit():
        OutFile.write(date0+line[8:])
        date0=line_date
    else:
        date0=date_init #Start from the first date
        OutFile.write(line)
open(inputFile,'r').close()
OutFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module to edit files in place, like so:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    # Whatever is written to stdout or with print replaces
    # the current line
    if line.startswith("address:"):
        print("address:xxx")
    elif line.startswith("age:"):
        print("age:20")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Simply pass the filename as an argument to the python command, for example:

```
python myprogram.py data.txt
```